# history of www pages developing

Tags: html

I'm looking for materials about history of the internet pages developing, from first page writting in CERN, to today - HTML5, frameworks etc. Have somebody any interesting books or other interesting materials about this topic? Or can tell me what bigest steps was in pages developing history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [link](http://www.internetsociety.org/internet/what-internet/history-internet) which provides many good articles about the history of the internet.

Also a very interesting website is [waybackmachine](http://archive.org/web/) with which you can take a look how the internet pages looked like in the early days

Comment: thanks! maybe somebody have different materials? :)